# Expect script call to another expect script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, expect

When I have two bash script like:

```
#script1.sh
echo "aaa"
script2.sh

#script.sh
echo "bbb"
```

And when I run script1.sh, I got both "aaa" and "bbb" prints in my console. While for expect script:

```
#script1
puts aaa
exec script2

#script2
puts bbb
```

I only get "aaa" prints in my console. Is that script2 is running background? (I know it is running since when sleep is added to script2, I see it stucks there for some time)

How can I get both "aaa" and "bbb" with this two expect script?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`exec script2` executes `script2` and returns its output - but it does not print the output to stdout.

You can use

```
#script1
puts aaa
puts [exec script2]
```

and

```
#script2
puts bbb
```

to explicitly print the output of `script2`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, exec replaces the current process with the new one. For example, `exec ls` terminates the bash process.